# Limit wifi bitrate

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi

My wifi connection is unstable at high speeds. Basically, whenever my wireless adapter negotiates a high speed with the wifi router (because it believes the signal is strong enough), the file transfer stalls as illustrated in this screenshot [image: as illustrated in this screenshot]. At low speeds, the transfer is stable. Is there a way to limit the bitrate artificially at a lower level? I tried `iwconfig wlo1 rate 24M auto`, but this had no effect.

My wifi adapter is an Intel Wireless-AC 9560 802.11 ac Dual Band 2x2 WiFi, driver: iwlwifi on Kubuntu 22.04.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `iwconfig` show power management on?

Comment: Yes, it is. I also tried turning it off, which showed some effect (i.e., the rate is changed when I type `iwconfig wlo1 rate 24M auto`), but rather inconsistently, meaning that the rate also exceeds my specified limit sporadically and sometimes for long periods even.

Comment: Check `modinfo -p iwlwifi` as there are some options to limit what wifi protocols are used